# Dynamic Database Storage

Tags: database, forms, dynamic, rdbms

I want to build a service that can store dynamic fields. For example, a registered user can create, read, update and delete generic form fields dynamically in a specific area of the application and persist the dynamic form in a database. These generic form fields would store what ever information the user requires. What is the best way to approach such a problem? (This is a database design question)

Comment: What have you searched for? do you have limitations? other requirements? your question would be more helpful if it addresses some specific group of products or possible solutions, say a NoSQL storage like couchDB or MongoDb, or a posible RDBMS solution, like the Magento database desing.
http://couchdb.apache.org/
http://www.mongodb.org/
Entity Attribute Value Model: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not consider a No SQL document store like MongoDB, CouchDB, Riak, etc.?

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar once.

The minimum design i would use would be something like this:

You need three tables to define the form metadada:

Form:

- FormID (PK)
- FormName
- etc

FormFields:

- FormFieldID (PK)
- FieldID
- FormID

Fields:

- FieldID (PK)
- FieldName
- FieldType
- etc

And two table to store form instance data:

FormInstaces:

- FormInstanceID (PK)
- FormID
- UserID
- etc

FormFieldInstances:

- FormFieldInstanceID (PK)
- FormInstanceID
- FormFieldID
- Value (this has to be text, you have to manage type conversion)

It's not the best of designs i know, but you can even support multivalued fields with this.
Type conversion should be managed at the application level

Comment: For the sake of performance, i wanted to not store all generic fields in one table...

Comment: So, you mean then a specialized table (or field) for each data type? Why would there be a performance hit?